# Shorted names of files in JTable

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, rowsorter

J have just made project - File Commander. I have a problem with names of files in `JTable`, it display its absolute path but I want to display only alone name file / dir. If I used `file.getName` in my `TableModel` it is okay, but if I click on dir it behaves as a `String`.

In short I need to display files from dir in `JTable` with names but it must behave like File after click on it.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom renderer for that column.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information and examples. In your case you can modify the example renderer that overrides the `setValue()` method to display the filename instead of the whole path.